# Springboot Logback.xml

Tags: spring-boot, logback

I have created a logback.xml file on a springboot project as below but after I run the application my console is flooded by pool status. How can I fix this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <charset>UTF-8</charset>
        <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %level --- [%thread] %logger : %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>logs\\ipf\\ipf-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log</fileNamePattern>
        <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
            <maxFileSize>2MB</maxFileSize>
        </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <charset>UTF-8</charset>
        <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %level --- [%thread] %logger : %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
<logger name="org" level="info" additivity="true">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
</logger>
<root level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
</root>
</configuration>
```

My console is flooded as below:

```
11:10:39.696 DEBUG --- [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool : HikariPool-1 - Pool stats (total=10, active=0, idle=10, waiting=0)
11:11:09.697 DEBUG --- [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool : HikariPool-1 - Pool stats (total=10, active=0, idle=10, waiting=0)
11:11:39.698 DEBUG --- [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool : HikariPool-1 - Pool stats (total=10, active=0, idle=10, waiting=0)
11:12:09.699 DEBUG --- [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool : HikariPool-1 - Pool stats (total=10, active=0, idle=10, waiting=0)
11:12:39.699 DEBUG --- [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool : HikariPool-1 - Pool stats (total=10, active=0, idle=10, waiting=0)
11:13:09.701 DEBUG --- [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool : HikariPool-1 - Pool stats (total=10, active=0, idle=10, waiting=0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with following file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <charset>UTF-8</charset>
        <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %level --- [%thread] %logger : %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>logs\\ipf\\ipf-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log</fileNamePattern>
        <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
            <maxFileSize>2MB</maxFileSize>
        </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <charset>UTF-8</charset>
        <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %level --- [%thread] %logger : %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
<logger name="org" level="info" additivity="true">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
</logger>
<root level="info">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
</root>
</configuration>
```

Comment: The flooding stopped. But the logs are not saved. I really need to save it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also override the logging for individual packages like

```
logging.level.ROOT=DEBUG
logging.level.com.zaxxer.hikari.pool=INFO
```

You can put these properties in your application.properties to control the logging for specific libraries.